# How to position a popover depending on which segment (UISegmentedControl) has been selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, uistoryboardsegue

I have programmatically created a custom cell of a dynamic table by integrating a segmentedcontrol of 8 segments.

It works well but once I tap on one of the segments, I would like that a popup menu with options appears near the cell and not at the lower end of the tableview.

I suppose that this occurrs because I have anchored the segue to the tableview. I would like to avoid to assign to each segment a segue to the popup menu.

Is there any possibility of re-positioning the popup menu automatically depending on the segment selected?

Here is the relevant code at the main view controller .m file

```
-(void)segmentSelectedAtRow: (UISegmentedControl *)sender{
if (self.flipsidePopoverController) {
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToChangeValues" sender:sender];
}

UITableViewCell *theParentCell = [[sender superview]superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfSegment = [self.spreadSheetView indexPathForCell:theParentCell];

...
}

...

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(POTFlipsideViewController *)controller {

[self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToChangeValues"]) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate = self;
}
}

@end
```

here is the flipside .h file

```
@class POTFlipsideViewController;

@protocol POTFlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(POTFlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface POTFlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <POTFlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
....
 @end
```

here is the relevant code for the flipside .m file

```
#import "POTFlipsideViewController.h"

@interface POTFlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation POTFlipsideViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);
 [super awakeFromNib];
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
return YES;
}

 - (IBAction)done:(id)sender
 {
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: Show (edit into your question) the code you are using to present the popup.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I am new in this forum and I do not know if the information provided is correct, useful and/or to extensive. Please let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: I suggested adding code to improve the chances of getting a response.  Sorry I haven't used storyboards so am not able to answer myself.  You may want to try removing code that is not essential to the issue (there's a bit too much right now) and perhaps add some more details or things you've tried.  An edit will bring the question back to the front.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina First of all thank you very much for your time and comments. I have tried not to use the storyboard as you have suggested and made the popover programmatically w/o the stroyboard and it works fine, since I can init the popover with presentPopoverFromRect at any place I want and it is not fixed to an anchor.